# How to sync firebase with react functional components?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, rebase

I am building a simple React app, using functional components (instead of classes). Therefore, there is no *this* to use as context when syncing the database with state data (in this case, hooks).

The code I'm supposed to do use within the function component is the following

useEffect(() => {
     base.syncState('/', {
       context: this,
       state: 'messages'
     })
   });

The problem is, as you see, that *this* means nothing in a function. So of course it doesn't work. It displays *REBASE: The options argument must contain a context property of type object. Instead, got undefined*

I guess the solution is simple, but as I'm new in React I can't figure out any clue to solve this.

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas.

Comment: Hi Xav, did you solve this issue?(I'm having the exact same issue) If so, would you mind sharing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can imitate `this` as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ref = base.syncState(endpoint, {
    context: {
      setState: (stateChange) => setState({ ...stateChange[stateName] }),
      state,
    },
    state: stateName
  })

  return () => {
    base.removeBinding(ref);
  }
}, [stateName])
```

But there may be a more modern way of doing it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ref = firebase.db.ref(endpoint);
  ref.on('value', snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.val()) setState(snapshot.val());
  });
}, [stateName]);
```

Details are here: https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base/issues/264